# Incorrect count of featured questions

Tags: support, user-interface

The featured questions page seems to display only 3 of 4 questions with a bounty. The screenshot says it all:

[image: Where'd 'e go?]

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: It currently displays correctly, but there was a short time when the count was wrong. Is this simply a delayed update thing?

Comment: Did you try clicking on that 99? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you simply caught the page in a brief period of time while the old featured count was cached. There was a bounty that was awarded at 17:00:48Z, which is about 11 minutes before you posted this Meta question. I can only guess, but I expect that your time that you visited the featured list was consequently just after the bounty was awarded.

Comment: Okay so should I change any question tags?

Comment: Pardon? I'm sorry, I don't see what question tags have to do with any of this.

Comment: As in I've tagged bug but it may not count as a bug?

Comment: Oh, that, @Sadly. Well, for the same reason I'm staying the addition of a [status-bydesign], I'm staying a classification retag (my answer is derived from logical conclusion rather than from experience or knowledge of the phenomenon). You originally thought it was a bug, no?

Comment: I suspected it was a bug because I couldn't see why the updates would be out of sync. Then I thought about it more and wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the Featured Questions are tagged with a tag you have set to ignore and hide, then you will see only the questions which you *don't* have ignored.

Comment: Useful to know, but I haven't ignored any tags (I didn't even know you could do that).